# Why does the replace function throw an error?

Tags: dplyr, replace, missing-data

I'm trying to replace the missing values in specific columns in my data with a 0.

This is my code:

```
ue <- ue %>%
  select(ost, west, sued, sued.ost, sued.west, ost.west, gesamtes_haus)%>% 
  replace_na(0)
```

When I run this, I get an error saying: Error: 'replace' must be a list.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

`replace_na` needs a list of the columns you want to replace. Try

```
ue %>% 
    select(ost, west, sued, sued.ost, sued.west, ost.west, gesamtes_haus) %>%
    replace_na(list(ost = 0, west = 0, sued = 0, sued.ost = 0, sued.west = 0, ost.west = 0, gesamtes_haus = 0))
```